# iPhone programming, cannot find resource at path?

Tags: ios4, resources, ios-simulator

I wonder if any of you could help with this problem. The following code is trying to access an audio file '4sSweepReverse.wav' at a path location determined and contained within the char *path. This code works absolutely fine when run in the simulator, but does not work when it is run on the iphone?

```
//print out the file path
NSLog(@"FilePath: ");
NSLog(filePath);


//Cast filePath from NSString, to Char array pointer. Needed to get reference to audio file.
const char *path = [filePath cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];

//get a ref to the audio file, need one to open it
CFURLRef audioFileURL   = CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation (NULL, (const UInt8 *) path, strlen (path), false);

//open the audio file
OSStatus result = AudioFileOpenURL (audioFileURL, 0x03, kAudioFileWAVEType, &mAudioFile);

//were there any errors reading? if so deal with them first
if (result != noErr) {
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Could not open file: %s", filePath]);
    packetCount = -1;
}
```

I know the path contained within the file is correct. The path on the simulator is

```
/Users/sam2/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/A355770A-6942-4E1F-BB8D-8A1B1906B42C/audioRecorder.app/4sSweepReverse.wav
```

And the path on the iPhone is

```
/var/mobile/Applications/2273E045-0A63-439E-A6AC-FD85CD30F7F2/audioRecorder.app/4sSweepReverse.wav
```

But when debugging the application running on the iPhone i get a -43 error (or File not found) ?

If anyone can help that would be awesome!
Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, i feel like a bit of an idiot now! Thanks for all your suggestions guys, turns out that the iPhone was finding the file, but I was opening it with the permission flags '0x03' which is read/write permissions, and obviously as a resource I can only access it with '0x01' read only permissions.

Here is the correct line of code:

```
    //open the audio file
OSStatus result = AudioFileOpenURL (audioFileURL, 0x01, kAudioFileWAVEType, &mAudioFile);
```

Once again, thanks for all your help!!

Comment: +1: Great!  You might want to use the pre-defined enum kAudioFileReadPermission to help avoid missing things like this.

Answer (score 1):

Is the resource in the project named exactly "4sSweepReverse.wav" and not perhaps (for example) "4ssweepreverse.wav" (all lowercase)?

The device file system is case-sensitive but the simulator is not.
See Apple QA1697: [Why doesn't my device load a file that loads fine in the Simulator?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1697.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Yes the resource is named exactly '4sSweepReverse.wav' This is why I can't understand it?

Comment: How is filePath actually set?  What is the exact output of the NSLogs on the sim and device?

Comment: filePath is set here:

'[sineSweep open:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1sSweepReverse" ofType:@"wav" inDirectory:nil]];'

This is opening a new instance of class (InMemoryAudioFile) which is where the original code posted is located.

The Paths shown in the original post are copied / pasted directly from the console running in debug mode on the sim and the device.

Comment: EIDT: The filePath is set like so:
'[sineSweep open:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1ssweepreverse" ofType:@"wav"]];'

Answer (score 0):

A few things that you might want to try -

- Remove, re-add the resource
- Clean build.
- Reset iPhone simulator Use a simpler or atleast a different name till you can get this to work,
  something like a.wav maybe? Not sure if a copy of the resource is being cached somewhere.
- Also not sure if having a number to start the filename has any effect on it (Probably not, but what the hell, might as well give it a go)